# How to get "Vendor Email Address" using "$order_id" (WooCommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a custom plugin to send an email to vendor when "new order received". Here I have used "YITH WooCommerce Multi Vendor / Marketplace" plugin to manage the vendors.

```
function send_vendor_notification( $order_id ) {
  $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
  $items = $order->get_items();

  foreach ( $items as $item ) {
   $product_name = $item['name'];
   $product_id = $item['product_id'];
   $product_variation_id = $item['variation_id'];
  } 

  $vendor_email = "dilshanudawatta15@gmail.com";
  $subject = 'New Order Received';
  $message = 'You have received a new order (#' . $order_id . '). Product 
  Name : (#' . $product_name . ') Product ID : (#'. $product_id .').';

  wp_mail( $vendor_email, $subject, $message );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'send_vendor_notification' );
```

This is my function to send an email to vendor. Here I have hardcoded the $vendor_email. This function is working. But I want to find a way to access $vendor_email using $order_id. Woocommerce REST API has not a endpoint to directly access vendor details from latest order.

Can I use "yith_get_vendor" for this? and Is there any easy way to access the vendor email using order id?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `$order_id`, you can get access to the vendor's email like this:

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$vendor_id = yith_get_vendor( $order_id, 'vendor' )->id;
$vendor = get_wcmp_vendor( $vendor_id );
$vendor_email = $vendor->user_data->user_email;
echo $vendor_email;
```

First, you fetch the `$order` object and then the `$vendor_id`. Then you can use that id to get the `$vendor` object and it's email.